# Fetching JSON in C# Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fetch

I'm trying to use my JSON API in Xamarin Forms (C#). The API can return:

When it fails: `{"status":"failed"}`

When everything is okay: `{"status":"success","time":"03.06.2016 13:15","data":["Thats a cool text","And thats another text"]}`

I'm currently doing this:

```
var client = new HttpClient ();
var url = "http://domain/plan/web/get/" + userclass;

var response = await client.GetAsync (url);
var data = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ().Result;
```

But now, I need to:

- Fetch the JSON data into an array or something
- Display an alert when the API returns failed (with DisplayAlert())
- When the API returns success, get the time, and set the data (the two or more strings at the end of the API result) to a label or a list view.

How can I do that?

Comment: Create a class that handle you JSON data. Use Newtonsoft.json Nuget Package to convert json to object.

Comment: But how to fetch the data like the two strings, because it's like an array in the JSON.

Comment: Create a model to handle your data and then you use `JsonConvert.Serialize(yourobject)` to turn it into a string and when you fetch it you Deserialize your string to get back your object `JsonConvert.Deserialize<yourobject>(jsonstring);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step you need to do is creating a class that can handle your JSON Data. In this case I would do:

```
public class APIResponse
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
    public List<string> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to create you need to create a method to make the GET request. This can be acomplished by doing this:

```
    public async Task <APIResponse> GetDataFromAPI(string query){
                try
                {
                    var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient ();
                    client.BaseAddress = "http://domain/";
                var response = await client.GetAsync("plan/web/get"+query);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var responseJSON = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var msg  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(responseJSON);

                return msg;
            }

            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                var msg = new APIResponse ();
                msg.status = "failed";

                return msg;
            }

}
```

Then in your page you call the method using:

```
APIResponse data = await GetDataFromAPI("yourquery");
if(data.status.Equals("success"){
     //Assign object values to label text property
}
else {
     DisplayAlert("Error","Something wrong happened", "OK");
}
```

Comment: Strange thing is here, I have the same code, except I get an error on the `APIResponse data = await GetDataFromAPI("yourquery");`, it gives `The name 'GetDataFromAPI' does not exist in the current context.` Any ideas?